# Python Hashing binary search

Tags: python

Write a binary_search function which at each step prints the list being searched as in the following output. It shows both the sublist currently being searched and then how that gets split into two parts around the midpoint.

This is what I have tried, but still struggle to find the solution:

```
def binary_search(a_list, item):
    print(a_list)  # just to show the search area
    if a_list == []:
        return False
    midpoint = len(a_list) // 2
    element = a_list[midpoint]
    if item == element:
        return True
    elif item < element:  # first half
        return binary_search(a_list[:midpoint], item)
    else:
        return binary_search(a_list[midpoint + 1:], item)
```

Given Input:

```
test_list = [0,1,2,8,13,17,19,32,42]
binary_search(test_list,3)
binary_search(test_list,13)
```

Expected output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 8, 13, 17, 19, 32, 42]
[0, 1, 2, 8] 13 [17, 19, 32, 42]
[0, 1, 2, 8]
[0, 1] 2 [8]
[8]
[] 8 []
[]
[0, 1, 2, 8, 13, 17, 19, 32, 42]
[0, 1, 2, 8] 13 [17, 19, 32, 42]
```

Comment: What's the problem with this? When I call it with `list(string.ascii_lowercase), 'p'`, it prints the whole list, then the o-z list, then o-t, then o-q, then returns True. When I call it with the same list and `2`, it prints the whole list, then a-m, a-f, a-c, a, nothing, then returns False. That seems like exactly what you wanted? If you have a test case that fails, please give us the input, and the desired and actual output. Read [mcve] in the help for more guidelines on asking an answerable question.

Comment: (besides, your code is incorrectly indented, please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to print the list to the left and right of the element, give this a try:

```
def binary_search(a_list, item):
    print(a_list) 
    if a_list == []:
        return False
    midpoint = len(a_list) // 2
    element = a_list[midpoint]
    left = a_list[:midpoint]
    right = a_list[midpoint+1:]
    print(left,element,right )

    if item == element:
        return True
    elif item < element: # first half
        return binary_search(left, item)
    else:
        return binary_search(right, item)
```

Input:

```
test_list = [0,1,2,8,13,17,19,32,42]
binary_search(test_list,3)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 8, 13, 17, 19, 32, 42]
[0, 1, 2, 8] 13 [17, 19, 32, 42]
[0, 1, 2, 8]
[0, 1] 2 [8]
[8]
[] 8 []
[]
```